# Is there a way to 'simplify' the VSCode debugger to be more like Chrome's?

Tags: xml, api, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools, vscode-debugger

I make an API call that contains XML.

I want to look at the response of the API in debug mode so that I can try accessing different properties of the example.

In code:

```
function XMLAPI() {
  var config = {
    //config settings
  };

  axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      const parsedResponse = parser.parseFromString(response.data, "text/xml");
      // See photo for what `parsedResponse` looks like in VSCode bebugger.
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

But when I type `parsedResponse` into the debug console on VSCode, it gives:
[image: parsedResponse, response]

Meanwhile, using Postman, I can see the actual XML. I copied a portion of this XML over to Chrome and in devtools and did as follows:

[image: parsedResponse, response]

This is a lot simplier looking than in VSCode. So, is there a way to simplify the VSCode debugger?